# Eclipse AndroidManifest Error- simply /> error

Tags: android

The following error occurs in Eclipse in my AndroidManifest file. Whereever I put the "/>", the same error occurs.

*Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
        Element type "permission" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". AndroidManifest.xml /KamilMaps  line 15 XML Problem*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Kamilmaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>


    <permission
        android:name="com.Kamilmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

 **>>>here error**

     <uses-permission android:name="permission_nazwa"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Kamilmaps.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>



    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBjZ4HIRVFoAtZocsidnC2EQ2RCFqusp-Q"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.Kamilmaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project? (Project->Clean)